# What's that accordion style book you can get at shrines called?

Tags: translation, words, religion

When visiting shrines or temples, one can get an accordion style book and for a couple hundred yen have a shrine's seal stamped inside. What is this book called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's [[御朱印帳]{ごしゅいんちょう}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%B1%E5%8D%B0_(%E7%A5%9E%E7%A4%BE%E4%BB%8F%E9%96%A3)).

[image]